# Resolving Java dependencies for JRuby

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, rake, jruby

I'm currently working on a Java class whose dependencies are resolved by maven. I now try to integrate the class into a JRuby script. 
Is it possible to manage the java dependencies such that the corresponding .jar files and the Java class file are handed over to JRuby automatically?

I have tried to call JRuby from maven, but wasn't able to fix the dependencies. Is there a possibility of handing over the correct maven class path inside the pom.xml file?

Thanks a lot, Philipp

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12357199/1272477

Answer (score 0):

It's not *quite* what you're after, but you might take a look at [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven) and compile your Java 'with dependencies', using the [`assembly:single`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html) plugin/goal. Then your JRuby scripts only need to reference a single jar to work.

Whether it's a useful idea or not is dependent on your needs, and how you want to distribute your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jruby</groupId>
    <artifactId>jruby</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Add this to *pom.xml* and try. This should automatically pull the Jruby jar for your project.