# Unable to access jar dependencies from JRuby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jar, jruby

I have created a gem on my local system for text mining which relies on
external Java libraries for classification tasks. I'm trying to harness
the power of Java through JRuby here. Directory structure is as follows:

```
- classifier/
 * classifier.gemspec
 * Gemfile
 * Gemfile.lock
 * lib/
     * classifier/
         * version.rb
         * sample_classifier.rb
     * classifier.rb
     * java/
         * sample_lib.jar
         * another_sample_lib.jar
         * yet_another_sample_lib.jar
 * Rakefile
```

I'm loading these jars in `lib/classifier.rb` as

```
Dir["java/*.jar"].each{|jar| require jar}
```

I have added this gem to a Git repository and referenced it in the
Gemfile of my Rails 3.0.9 project. However, my sample_classifier.rb
fails to locate any classes 'import'ed from any of the jars under
`lib/java`.

Things work if I copy `lib/java` to my Rails application

```
lib/ directory
```

and add the following in `sample_classifier.rb`:

```
Dir["lib/java/*.jar"].each{|jar| require jar}
```

However, I don't think it's a good practice to spill the gem's
dependencies in my Rails app. Is there a better way to achieve this? I
looked around for bundling jar files with a gem but I found results for
exactly the opposite i.e. bundling gems within a jar file. Can I add
these jars to Rails' config.autoload_path or similar to load them when
the application starts? Is it a good practice to bundle jar dependencies
with the gem?

I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Might I suggest that managing your Jars with [LockJar](https://github.com/mguymon/lock_jar) would be easier. Just install the gem

```
gem install lock_jar
```

#### Create a Jarfile

Create a [Jarfile](https://github.com/mguymon/lock_jar/blob/master/README.md#jarfile) that contains a list of your Jar dependencies:

```
jar "com.tobedevoured:example1:0.0.1"
jar "com.tobedevoured:example2:0.0.2"
jar "com.tobedevoured:example3:0.0.3"
```

The simplest jar notation is *groupId:artifactId:version*. Other supported variations are *groupId:artifactId:type:version* and *groupId:artifactId:type:classifier:version*.

#### Generating a Jarfile.lock

The transitive dependencies are resolved, download, and generate to a [Jarfile.lock](https://github.com/mguymon/lock_jar/blob/master/README.md#jarfilelock) with the [command line](https://github.com/mguymon/lock_jar/blob/master/README.md#command-line):

```
lockjar lock
```

(You can also run it from Ruby as [LockJar.lock](https://github.com/mguymon/lock_jar/blob/master/README.md#resolving-dependencies))

#### Accessing your Jars

The *Jarfile.lock* contains all the Jar dependency information. Now you can load your jars from the *Jarfile.lock* to the classpath with:

```
LockJar.load
```

When packaging with a Gem, you will need to ensure the Jars from *Jarfile.lock* have been downloaded with:

```
LockJar.install
```

Make sure you request the *Jarfile.lock* is relative to the Gem's installed dir. Here is an example helper:

```
module Example
  def self.installHelper
    # get jarfile relative the gem dir from lib/example.rb
    lockfile = File.expand_path( "../../Jarfile.lock", __FILE__ ) 

    LockJar.install( :lockfile => lockfile )
  end

  def self.loadHelper
    # get jarfile relative the gem dir from lib/example.rb
    lockfile = File.expand_path( "../../Jarfile.lock", __FILE__ ) 

    LockJar.load( :lockfile => lockfile )
  end
end
```

You can also setup your Gem to [download the Jar dependencies when the Gem installs](https://github.com/mguymon/lock_jar/blob/master/README.md#gem-integration), removing the need to call `LockJar.install`.

Comment: Thanks! `LockJar` looks interesting. Please let me try it out and I'll be back with my results.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute paths like so:

```
jars_dir = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'java')
for jar in Dir["#{jars_dir}/*.jar"]
  require jar
end
```

Comment: I belive `require "#{File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'java')}/*.jar` should also work.